# Синхронизация директорий

Tags: ос, синхронизация

Есть два компьютера, на одном Win7, на другом Ubuntu. На каждом лежит по папке с изображениями и видео, с кучей подпапок, общим весом ~500Гб. Компьютеры находятся на разных концах города. Связать их через интернет проблематично. Есть флешка на 64Гб. Как можно синхронизировать эти папки? Желательно за одну поездку, разница скорее всего меньше 64Гб.

Comment: Ну, для синхронизации нужно знать, какие где есть файлы и даты их изменения. Напишите скрипт, который пройдется по этой папке на обоих компьютерах, запишет в массив данные. А в конце просто проверьте вхождения, какие файлы различаются. Такие и копируйте.

Comment: За одну поездку в любом случае не получится. Если повезет, то минимум две.

Comment: @Sorg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Я и сам смутно понимаю, что надо выяснить различия, скопировать их на флешку и отвезти. Ну и в обратную сторону так же.
А вот какими утилитами это делать и в каком порядке, в каком формате сохранять инфу о файлах - вот это вопрос.

Comment: Но имейте ввиду, это форум разработчиков, если Вы ищете готовую тулзу для этого, то Ваш вопрос вводит в заблуждение и задан не по адресу.

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вам подойдет любой скриптовый язык. 
Первый скрипт:

1. Пройтись по папке и построить дерево, с указанием размера (в байтах) каждой ветки и листа.
2. Сохранить дерево в файл.

Высылаете этот скрипт на другой конец города, там его запускают, получают дерево в виде файла и высылают Вам его по почте.

Второй скрипт:

1. Парсинг файла-дерева и сверка со своей папкой, чтобы построить дерево, состоящее из того, что есть в Вашей папке, но чего нет на другом конце города.
2. По полученному дереву создаете систему папок на флешке и заполняете ее недостающими данными.

Теперь надо поехать туда и скопировать все, что родилось таким образом. Я бы рекомендовал python для этих нужд.

Comment: Может быть, вместо размера лучше считать какую-нибудь checksum? 

Например, в Linux можно использовать утилиту md5sum (наверняка ее же и для винды можно найти).

Comment: Самописные скрипты - это немного не то, что хотелось бы. Разве нету готовых утилит для подобного? Cинхронизация же - стандартная процедура...

Comment: @Sorg, скорее всего, каждый скрипт будет не более 15ти строк на python. На некоторых других скриптовых языках и того меньше. Т.е. вероятность найти какое-то кроссплатформенное ПО синхронизации именно с Вашими особенностями синхронизации достаточна, чтобы дешевле было написать эти 30 строк.

Comment: @avp, да, это будет более общее решение, на случай, если существуют разные картинки в одной директории, с одним именем и одного размера.

Answer (score 0):

Так а если облачное хранилище использовать? Например, https://www.yunio.com/ даёт 100 гигабайт облака бесплатно.

Comment: На том конце города интернет медленный и трафик ограниченный.